# How Can I send the Random Value through a Button?

Tags: ios, button, random, int, modulus

I am currently writing a program which generates an `answer` value that is between 1 and 100:

```
int answer = 0;
answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
```

I begin by having the user guess the value in a field on the screen.  The script will then run a simple loop to determine if the value they entered matches the random `answer` value.

At this point, I have an initial screen which asks for the user’s guess.  They type in a number and click a button to submit the value.  The problem is that if they do not guess the `answer` value right from the first entry then the answer value is regenerated and applied to a new random value on each button click.

My question then is how I can have the random value generated at the onset of the view and then maintained until the user has correctly guessed that value.

My attempt was to relocate this:

```
int answer = 0;
answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
```

to the beginning of the page, but then I get errors showing up stating there is a missing identifier for `answer` when the method is called later on the page.  Thank you for the assistance it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is because you put the random generation snippet inside your IBAction, as you stated in your comment:

> this is the method which takes the value submitted in the field

which means the code inside guessNow:sender will be triggered every time the user clicks on the button, that means you generate a random number every time the user submits a guess which makes no sense.

```
//this is the method which takes the value submitted in the field and changes the label display after the user clicks the guess now button

- (IBAction)guessNow:(id)sender {

//set the random siri guess value between 1 and 100

int answer = 0;
answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;

self.usersGuess = self.guessNumberField.text;
```

you should put that code block inside viewDidLoad() and add a property _answer to your .h

Here is a quick solution, I did not write this on XCode so might have syntax error

in your .h, add

```
@property (strong) int _answer;
```

in your .m, remove this from guessNow:sender

```
int answer = 0;
answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
```

and add this to your viewDidLoad()

```
answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
```

Also you might want to add another button to reset the random number, so I would say to isolate the random number generation out to a private method like this in your .m

```
- (void)generateRandomNumber
{
    self.answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
}
```

So that, you can use this method in your viewDidLoad() to generate the initial random number and use it for reset button, if any

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried this but I get this message from .h `property with retain or strong must be of object type`.  So I set the property as `@property (strong) NSObject _answer;`. This gives me an `undeclared identifier` in my .m  for `answer` in `answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;`

Comment: I mentioned that I don't have IDE handy, so sorry, my mistake, you don't need strong for int. Try this, in your .h, right after @interface line, put { int _answer; }

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this one Evan.  I have attempted this, but `answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;` still gives me an undeclared identifier.

Comment: If you put "int _answer" in .h, be sure to use "_answer" in .m instead of just "answer"